# mintty on Cygwin: how to change line spacing

Tags: command-line, cygwin, mintty

I have cygwin installed on windows 7.  Previously, there was no space between lines.  I was able to fit ~90 lines on my screen.  For some reason, now there is a small (looks like 2 pt) space between every line, and now I can only fit ~75 lines on screen.

I first noticed this when I was goofing off with an ascii autobot symbol.  It used to be smooth, but now it looks like this:

[image]

It's pretty annoying that I've lost 15 lines per screen.  It makes tracking log files more difficult.  Is it possible to edit this somehow?  I haven't been able to find a line spacing option anywhere.

Comment: I just updated Cygwin and noticed this myself. Since I use misc-fix 7x14, a RowSpacing=-1 gives me how it looks before (though I may try -2 to get more lines in my terminal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding

```
RowSpacing=-2
```

to `~/.minttyrc` solved it for me. You might want to try different (negative) values depending on the font you use. I prefer Lucida Console 9, setting RowSpacing to -2 restored the look as it was before [Mintty version 2.2.4](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/Changelog#224-20-mar-2016).